# Page and admin doesnt load - i tried everything

Tags: pages, wp-admin

My problem is that I can't login to wp-admin.

I tried everything:

- removing .htaccess file;
- changing names of all folder in wp-content to force to use defaults
- in database is everything ok i checked;
- domain is active;
- i added to wp-config lines : define ('WP_HOME') and define('WP_SITEURL')

When I go to my page or when i tried to login to wp-admin i'm redirected to Hosting page.

Thank in advance for all your help !

Comment: What's this hosting page you're being redirected to? When you say you can't login to WP Admin can you be more specific? It tells you your password is wrong? It gives you an error message? Blank screen? Sends you back to login page as if nothing happened? Use the edit link on the question to add as much detail as possible, be clear if it redirects somewhere, where does it redirect to? If it doesn't load then what happens instead?

Comment: It's send me to hosting page. This happen when i tried to go to my page, or try open wp-admin. Writing i can't login to wp-admin i mean that I don't see any login page. I'm immediately redirected to hosting page. In this page is only information that this domain exist.

Comment: That might not be a WP issue then, it might be a DNS issue. Double check that when you added new A records that you removed the old ones. Otherwise the solution to this will be either with your hosting provider, or DNS

Comment: Thank You very much. You was right. That was DNS issue!